# Accidently deleted the device calender? Can I recover or add new?

Tags: calendar, sony-xperia-z2

My device is an Xperia Z2 D6503 running Android 4.4.4. I was using [iCal Import/Export CalDAV](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tk.drlue.icalimportexport) to import `.ical` files into my device calendar.

Using this same app, I accidently deleted my device calendar. I cannot see the 'device calendar' anymore in the list of calendars in my phone's default calendar app.

Can I recover this calendar or add a new device calendar? I am guessing iCal app has deleted `com.android.calender`.

Comment: are you rooted ?

Comment: @lord-ralf-adolf nope mate...

Comment: then how come an app uninstall a system app ? it's theoretically impossible ,may  be the stock calendar is just deactivated ,go to settings > applications > all and find the calendar app see if it's there if it is then click on it an click on activate

Comment: The calendar app is available and is enabled, but I cannot find the device calender in the list of calenders shown in the built-in calender app, it was there before it got deleted. I contacted the developer of the iCal app and he said if it got deleted, there's no way of recovering it. Now I am wondering if I can add a new calender to the device.

Comment: then may may be you hid the stock callender from the app drawer try installing a new launcher just to see if the new launcher shows the stock calendar app

Comment: @lord-ralf-adolf the "device calendar" is rather a kind of "special account", not an app. No idea how to re-create that natively, but e.g. [MyLocalAccount](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fjsoft.mylocalaccount) is able to provide an equivalent (there might be others, but that's the only one known to me).

Comment: @Izzy oh ,I see ,the opp should edit and clarify ,he explicitly said "I am guessing iCal app has deleted `com.android.calender` " com.android.calender is the stock calender app

Comment: @lord-ralf-adolf Yes, and a system app. So how likely is that? And then what should the "phone's default calendar app" be the OP is still using? I bet there's another way to restore the "device calendar" (maybe clearing cache+data from "calendar provider", after having backed up all calendar entries?), but I've never been in that situation – and while a factory-reset would definitely cure that, it's probably not what one prefers :)

Comment: @lzzy, I thought of factry-resetting which will definitely restore the device calender, but as u said its not the best thing to do.

Comment: I ran into the same problem. Even if you install a new calendar. Some apps try to create events to the default calendar and if it doesn't exist then it fails silently.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to download a new calendar.

I recommend you get [Google Calendar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.calendar&hl=en).

[image: google calendar]

Check [12 of the best calendar apps available for your Android smartphone today](http://thenextweb.com/apps/2013/08/16/12-of-the-best-calendar-apps-available-for-your-android-smartphone-today/), See if that helps.